# How to take multiple outputs from an action in the Activity Diagram in UML 2?

Tags: uml, activity-diagram

I am trying to draw an activity diagram in UML 2. I have an action called "splitter" which takes an object and split it into two groups of objects called A and B. These new objects undergo two different flows in the activity diagrams in parallel. I am wondering if UML2 supports taking multiple output from an action. How can I emphasize on the parallelism without using a fork symbol?

Answer (score 0):

Your action can have two outgoing data flows - either using pins or connecting the two outgoing links to different object nodes. After this from either the pins or the nodes you can start two different flows. There is no need to use fork.

Answer (score 0):

The activity diagram provides two kinds of flows: control flow and object flow. The "fork" is used for control flow only.
According you question it looks like you are talking about object flow. There is no any kind of "parallelism" in UML notation for object flow.